# StringUtils error in the join function for Scala code

Tags: java, arrays, string, scala

Here is my Scala code trying to join an Array of String:

```
var data:Array[String] = getMyArray(input)
val out = StringUtils.join(data, ",")
```

Then I got the following error that I couldn't figure out.

```
overloaded method value join with alternatives: (x$1: java.util.Collection[_],x$2: String)String <and> (x$1: java.util.Collection[_],x$2: Char)String <and> (x$1: java.util.Iterator[_],x$2: String)String <and> (x$1: java.util.Iterator[_],x$2: Char)String <and> (x$1: Array[Object],x$2: String)String <and> (x$1: Array[Object],x$2: Char)String cannot be applied to (Array[String], String)
```

Comment: To answer your original question, the error is occurring due invariance of Scala Arrays. Using the built-in solution like Binzi's makes more sense :)

Comment: Thanks! Would you please elaborate a bit more about "invariance of Scala Arrays"? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use mkString?

```
    scala> var data:Array[String]=Array("1","2")
    data: Array[String] = Array(1, 2)

    scala> data.mkString(",")
    res2: String = 1,2
```

Answer (score 1):

The `join` method defined like this:

```
    join(Object[] array, String separator)
```

For that can't apply it to your code.
According to the error `String can not be applied to (Array [String], String)`, the compiler does not consider String  as a `Object`.
Try to upgrade the version of library `Commons Lang`.

Comment: Would you please explain a bit more? data is String[] , why can't be employed?